# NSMigrationManager: what is this auto-generated, yet undocumented method?

Tags: xcode5, core-data-migration

I have created a mapping model in Xcode 5 and it has auto-generated some relationship mappings using `destinationInstancesForEntityMappingNamed:sourceInstances:`, which is appropriately documented.

However, it looks like in some cases, Xcode 5 is using this method

`destinationInstancesForSourceRelationshipNamed:sourceInstances`

when auto-generating some of the relationships.

The confusing thing is that it seems to be used for 1-M relationships, but in my case it's mistakenly assuming 1-M when it's actually 1-1.

[image]

The relationship between this entity and "order" is actually 1-1.

So given that Xcode 5 is likely wrong, **in what case should I be using `destinationInstancesForSourceRelationshipNamed:sourceInstances` or `destinationInstancesForEntityMappingNamed:sourceInstances:`**?